# Need a JCheckBox to come before JLabel but label coming little bit above from the base of checkbox

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Here is the code snippet:

```
public class Test {

    Test(){
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout gb=new GridBagLayout();
    panel.setLayout(gb);
    GridBagConstraints gc= new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gc.gridx=1;
    gc.gridy=0;

    String label="hello";
    JLabel l1=new JLabel(label);
    panel.add(l1,gc);
    gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gc.gridx=0;
    gc.gridy=0;

    JCheckBox check=new JCheckBox();
    check.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(label);
    panel.add(check,gc);

    f.add(panel);
    f.setSize(200, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t=new Test();
    }
}
```

checkbox and label are coming fine from left to right but the problem which I am facing is label is coming little bit above from the checkbox what should I do to make them come in same line ?

Comment: You better provide a short runnable program of your problem if you want to get better solution

Comment: Why not use `JCheckBox.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstant.LEFT)` and only have the checkbox? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setHorizontalTextPosition%28int%29

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). (Pretty much what @user3771102 was referring to.)

Comment: I provided the code above I want it to start from top left corner of JPanel and want it to be aligned in same line with nominal spacing

Comment: Why do you need that anchor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have tested your code it was because of the `gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;` the text is not aligning in the center of the checkbox. I don't get it why you needed that anchor but if you want to align the text and the checkbox to the left you can use `setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT)` as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name. Try running this code below you'll see that it's perfectly aligned.

```
 public class Testcheckbox {

        GridBagLayout gb = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        public Testcheckbox(){
        JFrame f=new JFrame();

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.NORTH_WEST));

        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(gb);

        String label="hello";
        JLabel l1=new JLabel(label);
        l1.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        // gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gc.weightx = 0;
        gc.weighty = 0;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(l1,gc);



        JCheckBox check=new JCheckBox();
        check.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(label);
        check.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        // gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        gc.weightx = 0;
        gc.weighty = 0;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(check,gc);

        f.add(content);
            content.add(panel);
        f.setSize(200, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);


    }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Testcheckbox t = new Testcheckbox();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Check my code above again and I have updated it. I have added another `panel` so that the layout of the `gridbag` is not affected by where you want to put the content of the `panel` in the `JPanel`. Did I get that right?

Comment: It is now coming in same line as of checkbox but the problem is I want it to be in the top left corner of Jpanel but its coming in west

Comment: @Nidhi check my answer again above I have edited it.